# Switch between dark and light theme in non-material ui component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to introduce a theme switcher in my app. I have a lot of non-material-ui elements that I need the theme to reflect the changes on them.

The code below shows that I have a state that is called `darkState` that is set to `true`. The material ui components in my app reflect those changes but for example the `div` below does not get the dark color of the dark theme. What is that I am doing wrong in here?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Header from "./components/Header.js";
import TopBar from "./components/TopBar.js";
import Sequence from "./components/Sequence.js";
import SecondaryWindow from "./components/SecondaryWindow.js";

import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import "./App.css";
import { MainContextProvider } from "./contexts/mainContext.js";

function App() {
    const [darkState, setDarkState] = useState(true);
    const palletType = darkState ? "dark" : "light";
    const theme = createMuiTheme({
        palette: {
            secondary: {
                main: "#0069ff",
            },
            type: palletType,
        },
    });
    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
        root: {
            paddingLeft: 80,
            height: "100%",
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
        },
    }));
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <MainContextProvider>
                <div className={classes.root}>
                    <Header />
                    <TopBar />
                    <Sequence />
                    <SecondaryWindow />
                </div>
            </MainContextProvider>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Not sure you want to be calling `createMuiTheme` inside your React components on every re-render. That could lead to some issues.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you only change the @material component not the CSS, to change the CSS Theme, you need to make variable for CSS for Dark Theme.

on `:root` declare all the light theme color and `div.darkmode` all the darkmode:

```
:root {
  --color-bg: #fff;
  --color-text: #000;
}

.div.darkmode {
  --color-bg: #363636;
  --color-text: #d1d1d1;
}

/** Usage */
.div {
   color: var(--color-text);
   background: var(--color-bg)
}
```

and make a condition on the `div` when the dark theme is true a new classname `darkmode` will be added to dive as you wrote above

```
<div className={`${classes.root} ${darkState && `darkmode`}`}>
    <Header />
    <TopBar />
    <Sequence />
    <SecondaryWindow />
</div>
```

I created [an example for you here](https://jsbin.com/jiviqosoma/edit?html,css,output).
let us know if anything goes wrong!

---

## workaround 2

if you're not doing any customer style by `CSS` file then this will work

```
import React from 'react';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';

export default function MyApp() {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      {/* The rest of your application */}
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: I like your solution but it does not utilize the theme functionality in Mui. Using this functionality means centralising the theming for HTML elements and Mui components. See my answer!

Comment: @SamiAl-Subhi I had the same issue two ago, Material UI will only their components not the CSS, you really need to define the CSS variable in order to achieve your goal! if you find other solution please share it with us, you will love to learn!

Comment: I posted my solution as answer to this question, please check it.

Comment: @SamiAl-Subhi I'm glad that you solve it by yourself! I'll give it shot for the next time, Thanks!

Comment: @SamiAl-Subhi I found the solution using `cssBaseLine`

Answer (score 1):

Now I know the answer, in my example, the class `root` is not able to benefit from the custom-created `theme` that is provided by `MuiThemeProvider`. Instead, it uses the original `theme` that comes in Mui. To solve this, I separated that `div` into a component. This way, the `theme` context (custom-theme from MuiThemeProvider) can be accessed by the `div`. This way when I switch `DarkState`, colors update on Mui components and HTML elements based on the custom theme palette.

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import Header from "./components/Header.js";
import TopBar from "./components/TopBar.js";
import Sequence from "./components/Sequence.js";
import SecondaryWindow from "./components/SecondaryWindow.js";

import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import "./App.css";
import { DndProvider } from "react-dnd";
import { HTML5Backend } from "react-dnd-html5-backend";
import { MainContextProvider } from "./contexts/mainContext.js";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function AppContent() {
    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
        root: {
            paddingLeft: 80,
            height: "100%",
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
        },
    }));
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <Header />
            <TopBar />
            <Sequence />
            <SecondaryWindow />
        </div>
    );
}
function App() {
    const [darkState, setDarkState] = useState(true);
    const palletType = darkState ? "dark" : "light";
    const theme = createMuiTheme({
        palette: {
            secondary: {
                main: "#0069ff",
            },
            type: palletType,
        },
    });
    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <MainContextProvider>
                <AppContent />
            </MainContextProvider>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate `data-theme` attribute to toggle the dark/light theme. Try it on **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/question-62976906?file=src/App.js)**.

### Setting up themes

Use `data-theme` attribute to set the selected theme.

```
/* default theme (light) */
:root {
  --primary-color: #302ae6;
  --secondary-color: #536390;
  --font-color: #424242;
  --bg-color: #fff;
}

/* dark theme */
[data-theme='dark'] {
  --primary-color: #9a97f3;
  --secondary-color: #818cab;
  --font-color: #e1e1ff;
  --bg-color: #161625;
}
```

### Switching theme in React Hooks

```
// App.js

const [theme, setTheme] = useState({
  light: true,
});

const handleChangeTheme = (event) => {
  setTheme({ ...theme, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });
};
```

**Set our `data-theme` attribute accordingly**

```
const currentTheme = theme.light === true ? 'light' : 'dark';
document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', currentTheme);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would declare both variations of your theme as constants above the mounting or rendering. This way you are not literally creating a new theme ever time your theme swaps. I would have a state holding the reference to the MUI-Theme constant.